# Android: Calling Parent Activity from Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am new to android and had just a very strange issue. I have one Activity say `A` and many fragments `f1,f2,f3` and so on, what I want is that when user opens app, fragment `f1` should get displayed as login fragment and after login mainActivity should be displayed.

Is this correct approach of doing it? I am using single activity and many fragments.

All suggestions in comments are welcome!

Comment: One Activity. Many Fragments. Okay first of all that's one way of architecting the app structure. If you are new to android please don't go by that design because it has lot of pitfalls

Comment: I don't see the advantage of using single activity-many fragment pattern. IMHO it seems complicated.

Comment: I needed a login before mainActivity get open up, should I use fragment for that or activity?

Comment: use an activity. Thats the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This is possibly a good approach. It would just depend on how you want to do it, and you definitely can do it this way. You could just use one activity and in your onCreate, determine which fragment to display based on whether or not a user is signed up/logged in. This is just an overview because I think you understand the basic idea. I prefer to pass fragments to a method named "showFragment" to swap out fragments.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

if(user.isLoggedIn())
{
showFragment(new MainFragment);
}
else
{
showFragment(new LoginFragment);
}
}


private void showFragment(Fragment yourFragment)
{
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager ();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
FragmentTransaction.add (R.id.yourFrame, yourFragment);
FragmentTransaction.commit();
}
}
```

It's good that you're using fragments early in your experience with Android. An approach similar to this should work for you. But also consider keeping your login stuff in a separate activity. Either way could work really.

Comment: should I keep my activity layout file empty?